# pipe part of a text file into downstream work (python)

Tags: command-line, awk, sed

I want to pipe part of a very large text file into downstream work (python).

Basically, I want get all the odd lines and first n characters of the even lines, but I still want to keep the line order.

The reason is that the even lines are very very long, but I only need first few characters. This can make reading the file into python much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in `awk`:

```
$ cat testfile 
foo
asdkjasjdka
bar
kjsdksjdkssd
$ awk -v n=2 'NR % 2 == 1 { print } NR % 2 == 0 { print substr($0, 1, n) }' testfile
foo
as
bar
kj
```